# Visual Studio - Page not found

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Today I selected "Work Items" as I have a million times before but this time I was met with this error along the top of my "Team Explorer" tab:

> "Page [some long GUID] not found."

This also happened for "Pending changes".

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To fix the issue simply run the below command in an elevated command prompt as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2013/11/21/quot-pending-changes-and-source-control-explorer-missing-from-team-explorer-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup
```

My understanding is this command forces the recreation (what Microsoft refers to as "merging") of current VS settings into what is apparently a corrupt settings cache. On the surface, **this is similar to deleting the directory path *C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version* and allowing visual studio to recreate it at launch**.  However, I prefer to not to delete this outright and instead rely on re-merge approach.

Recently I found this sometimes occurs when I launch several solutions at once (i.e. I have 1 or more Visual Studio instances loading a solution at the same time).  I also have ReSharper, SQL Prompt, VSCommands and TFS Power Tools installed which I'm sure contribute to some degree.

**UPDATE:**

This fix should work for ***all versions*** of Visual Studio, however you will need to execute the command in the directory appropriate to your version.  For example with Visual Studio 2015 the path would be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup
```

Version mappings for Visual Studio (original version mapping answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/194058/what-does-the-number-on-the-visual-studio-solution-icon-represent)):

- Visual Studio 2005 = 8
- Visual Studio 2008 = 9.0
- Visual Studio 2010 = 10.0
- Visual Studio 2012 = 11.0
- Visual Studio 2013 = 12.0
- Visual Studio 2015 = 14.0
- Visual Studio 2017 = Path has changed to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE"

Comment: Phew! This turned out to fix it. I was afraid it also resets my VS settings, but it didn't. Nice!

Comment: That would be nice to know exactly what this command is actually doing though... There is not much details "here"...

Comment: I just did this and it did indeed reset my VS settings. It did at least also fix the problem though.

Comment: @Bob Horn It should not reset your settings.  My understanding is this command forces the recreation (what Microsoft refers to as "merging") of current VS settings into what is apparently a corrupt settings cache.  On the surface, this is similar to deleting the directory path C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version> and allowing visual studio to recreate it at launch.

Answer (score 22):

Deleting all files in *ComponentModelCache* folder worked for me

For Visual Studio 2013:
**"*C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache*"**

For Visual Studio 2015:
**"*C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache*"**

or

**%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache**

Comment: In practice, this has been the swiss-army knife of solutions with Visual Studio.  I prefer attacking the specific problem and so I find my solution to be more desirable.

Answer (score 3):

If you get this issue in VS2015 and running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" /setup doesn't fix you issue you can try the following:

1. Close all instances of VS
2. Delete all files in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
3. run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" /setup

Answer (score 2):

This happend also with my installation of VS '13 when I installed VS '15.
Removing the files at 
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache"

did the job for me.

Comment: /setup did not help me. This (replaced 12 with 14 though) did.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem with you, and resolved by run the VS as administrator

Comment: @Haodo Hopefully your suggestion will be of use to others; however, I encountered this error while running as Administrator.  I have set Visual Studio to run as Administrator all of the time.

Comment: @Haodo, I do still receive this error infrequently.  When I do, the command I listed fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed. Please make sure you follow them in correct sequence. These steps are for VS 2015. Use 12.0 (instead of 14.0) for VS 2013 and 10.0 for VS 2010

1. Close all instances of VS
2. Delete all files in C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
3. Delete the folder C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
4. run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" /setup in a command prompt as administrator